# $watch on array in service not working in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to watch when an array in a service is updated. I update this array in the service using a function in a directive based controller. Now for some reason the watch function does not get called in the link function of the second directive. Why is watch not being called in the second directive. I am trying to update the scope of a variable in the second directive so that it updates when the first directive function updates the service.

The Service

```
var productServices = angular.module('productServices', ['ngResource']);
productServices.factory('PlayerListS', [function() {
    var playerList = [];

    function getList() {
        console.log(playerList);
        return playerList;
    }
    function addToList(name) {
        playerList.push(name);
    }

    return {
        addToList :addToList,
        getList: getList
    }
}]);
```

The Directives

```
'use strict';

bands.directive("player",['PlayerListS', function (PlayerlistS) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        person:'@person',
        add:'&add'
    },
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: "partials/player.html",
    controller: function($scope, $element, $compile) {
        $scope.playerList = ["A", "B"];
        $scope.add = function(name) {
            PlayerlistS.addToList(name);
            PlayerlistS.getList();

        }

    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

    }

};
}]);
bands.directive("playerList", ['PlayerListS', function (PlayerlistS) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    template: "<p>Test</p>",
     controller: function($scope, $element, $compile) {
    },
    link: function($scope, $el,$attrs) {
        console.log('added');
        var x = PlayerlistS.getList()

/*THIS IS WHERE THE WATCH IS HAPPENING*/
        $scope.$watch('x', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log("CHANGED");
        }, true);
    }

};
}]);
```

The Controller

```
var bands = angular.module('bands', []);
bands.controller('ViewHousesCtrl',  ['$scope', '$element', '$routeParams', '$q',
function ViewHousesCtrl($scope, $element, $routeParams, $q) {

    $scope.playerLis = ["A","B","C"];

}]);
```

HTML

```
   <player ng-show="true" person="RandomName" add="add()"></player>
   <player-list ng-show="true" ng-repeat="a in playerLis"></player-list>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console?

Comment: @Vivz no no error what so ever..

Comment: try `$watchCollection` once here is the example https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your watcher is really doing, is trying to watch a variable called `x` on the directive scope. But your variable `x` is just a regular local variable, so your watcher doesn't trigger. So what your watcher basically translates to is this:

```
$scope.$watch(function(scope){
    return scope['x'];
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log("CHANGED");
}, true);
```

You can probably see why it doesn't trigger. There is no variable `$scope.x`. Instead you should try watching the service directly, by specifying the watch function. Like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return PlayerlistS.getList();
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log("CHANGED");
}, true);
```

Comment: This works would you know how to apply the newVal so that the scope varible being used in the ng-repeat updates and the new values are shown?

Comment: Technically your ng-repeat just creates multiple instances of your playerList-directive. What I believe you really want, is to use the ng-repeat in your template of the `playerList`-directive. E.g. `<p ng-repeat="player in playerList">{{player}}</p>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling mistake in your HTML, it should be:

```
<player-list ng-show="true" ng-repeat="a in playerList"></player-list>
```